# Abstraction or Encapsulation?

Tags: java, android, abstraction

I have a method which reads an XML file and stores data from the XML file into private fields within my class.

I then use public Getters to get the private fields.

I understand this is basically encapsulation, however I saw an example online that was basically like my idea but they referred this similar logic as Abstraction.

Could someone tell me how this is abstraction?

Comment: You're hiding the details of reading and parsing an XML file behind a method call. That fits the definition of an abstraction. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_(software_engineering)

Answer (score 1):

I think it is both Encapsulation and Abstraction. Since any class is type of encapsulation and here you are hiding the complex details, so it abstraction too..